# How to pass dynamic table name in insert query in MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, dynamic, triggers

I am facing issue of passing dynamic table name in trigger in MySQL.

Here is my

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `demo_database`.`my_trigger`$$

create trigger `demo_database`.`my_trigger` AFTER INSERT on `demo_database`.`tablename` 

for each row BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a varchar(255); 
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name  LIKE '%_pbxware_minilcr'  limit 1,10000000000;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
     FETCH cur1 INTO a; 
     IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

    INSERT INTO a (`server`,`tbd`,`lcr`,`route`,`destination`,`trunk`,`ext`) values (3,NULL,'primary','11','1','78',NULL);

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur1;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here in above cur1 Cursor, I am fetching tables name and I want to insert value in that (fetched) tables..

Comment: Try this one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575631/workaround-for-dynamic-statements-in-stored-procedures-called-from-triggers