# How to write signal function in MYSQL that can be call from Triggers and Stored functions?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, stored-functions, mysql-5.0

In my Database I have a **table**: `Employee` with recursive association, an employee can be boss of other employee.

The Table Description:

```
mysql> DESC Employee;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN         | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| designation | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MSSN        | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Present State of Employee Table is:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;
    +-----+------+-------------+------+
    | SSN | name | designation | MSSN |
    +-----+------+-------------+------+
    | 1   | A    | OWNER       | 1    |
    | 2   | B    | BOSS        | 1    |  
    | 3   | C    | WORKER      | 2    |  
    | 4   | D    | BOSS        | 2    |  
    | 5   | E    | WORKER      | 4    |   
    | 6   | F    | WORKER      | 1    |  
    | 7   | G    | WORKER      | 4    |  
    +-----+------+-------------+------+
    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following is hierarchical relation among the rows in table:

```
     A
    / \
   B   F
  / \
 c   D
    / \
   G   E
```

**I wanted to impose following constraints on INSERT**:

- An employee can't BOSS of himself. This is allowed for OWNER only. Hence query like.
   `INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("8", "H", "BOSS",   "8");`
    Should be declined.
- New new `OWNER` can be inserted.

As I am working with MYSQL version previous than 5.5 (doesn't support signal).
So I am using a **my_singal()** a stored procedure.

Written Like this:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `my_signal`(in_errortext VARCHAR(255))
> BEGIN
>     SET @sql=CONCAT('UPDATE `', in_errortext, '` SET x=1');
>     PREPARE my_signal_stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE my_signal_stmt;
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE my_signal_stmt;
> END//
> ```

And **to Apply constraints** I `written a Trigger` as I came to know that `check constraints are not yet implemented in MySQL`!

> ```
> DELIMITER $$
> CREATE
>   TRIGGER `employee_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
>     ON `Employee`
>     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>       CASE
>        WHEN NEW.designation = 'OWNER'  THEN
>           CALL my_signal('Error: can not insert new OWNER !');
>
>        WHEN NEW.SSN = NEW.MSSN THEN
>           CALL my_signal('Error: Row can not reference itself!');
>       END CASE; 
>   END$$   
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

It was successfully compiled and loaded in database. But when I tried to insert:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("12", "K", "BOSS",   "12");
ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

I Learn [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568577/what-is-the-workaround-for-using-dynamic-sql-in-a-stored-procedure) that

- SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use **Dynamic SQL** (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

After some effort I could write an another trigger as below. **Working fine** as per my requirement.

> ```
> mysql> CREATE
>     -> TRIGGER `employee_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
>     ->     ON `Employee`
>     ->     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>     ->      IF UCASE(NEW.designation) = 'OWNER'  THEN  /*UCASE*/
>     ->        UPDATE `Error: can not insert new OWNER !` set x=1; 
>     ->      END IF;
>     ->      IF (NEW.SSN = NEW.MSSN) THEN
>     ->        UPDATE `Error: Row can not reference itself!` set x=1;
>     ->      END IF;
>     -> END$$
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
>
> mysql> DELIMITER ;
> mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("12", "K", 'owner',   "11");
> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'dumy.Error: can not insert new OWNER !'
>   doesn't exist
> mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("12", "K", 'Ajay',   "12");
> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'dumy.Error: Row can not reference itself!' 
>   doesn't exist
> ```

Cause I am already using `my_signal()`  in many procedures and I need to write many new Stored functions and triggers where I would need `my_signal()` functions again.

`It would also good for easy manipulation if sometime MYSQL version upgraded to 5.5(+)`.

**Can someone suggest me other way to write my_signal() through which I can print customized error message?**

I tried as follows:

> <del>DELIMITER $$</del> 
>    <del>CREATE PROCEDURE `my_signal`(in_errortext VARCHAR(255))</del> 
>      <del>DECLARE sql varchar(512);</del> 
>      <del>BEGIN</del> 
>      <del>SET sql=CONCAT('UPDATE `', in_errortext, '` SET x=1');</del> 
>      <del>UPDATE sql SET x =1;</del>  
>       <del>END$$</del>

But useless :( .

Please help me on this.I will be very thankful!

I am not good at MYSQL specially @ Stored Procedures.

If you would like to try on your system [here you can quickly find commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql) to build this database.

**EDIT ~** MySQL interpreter behaving as compiler!

We can't call **Dynamic SQL** statements from Triggers and Stored Functions.

To keep same interface my_signal() in all stored routine I modified my_signal(); Added `Static SQL` statements with `Dynamic SQL` and being sure that it will not executed from triggers. I thought it should be allowed `because MySQL is an interpreter not a compiler`.

**New my_signal()**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_signal`(in_errortext VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    IF in_errortext = 'ERROR_INSERT_OWNER' THEN  /* Static SQL*/
        UPDATE `Error: can not insert new OWNER !` set x=1; 
    END IF;

    IF in_errortext = 'ERROR_INSERT_SELF_REFERENCE' THEN /* Static SQL*/
        UPDATE `Error: Row can not reference itself!` set x=1;

    ELSE /* Dynamic SQL*/    
        SET @sql=CONCAT('UPDATE `', in_errortext, '` SET x=1');
        PREPARE my_signal_stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE my_signal_stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE my_signal_stmt;
    END IF;
END$$
```

**New Trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `employee_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `Employee`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        CASE
         WHEN UPPER(NEW.name) = 'OWNER'  THEN
            CALL my_signal('ERROR_INSERT_OWNER');

         WHEN NEW.SSN = NEW.MSSN THEN
            CALL my_signal('ERROR_INSERT_SELF_REFERENCE');
        END CASE; 
    END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

Hopefully I tried to insert:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("9", "X", "WOKER", "9" );
ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("9", "X", "OWNER", "9" );
ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

OOPs! its behaving like compiler but not interpreters. Is it not?

**EDIT**: Answer

While I was editing question luckily I got answer by [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba).
ANSWER IS [**HERE**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321/dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-routines/1906#1906)
Last: I could understand that **we cannot do Dynamic SQL in triggers.** and  I may have to resort to coding the my_signal(). No other option yet now in MySQL.

Comment: Can you restrict direct inserts into your table? I mean can you force front/back-end teams to use your stored procedures/functions to insert this table?

Comment: `Edited Question and added Answer` so that other can get help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, prior to MySQL 5.5 the only way to force a `ROLLBACK` from within a trigger is to generate an error just like you did intentionally.

This causes two problems.

1. the error message is very confusing for the developer since you can't return a custom error message
2. If a "real" error would be caused by the manipulating statment, under some circumstances you might even overwrite this 
   and make debugging even harder.

This is from the view of a developer - I had a lot of discussions with our DBA concerning this.. but even a well done database - especially if built on MySQL - sometimes must rely on the application. :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this: `Error messages are customised but error codes are not!` Also `**Dynamic-SQL** makes Stored-routines tough to debug'. But I don't have other option; my `MySQL version is old (5.1)`. In that case this is the only way for `interrupting triggers I mean in MySQL 5.1` ...I will handle the checks in at back-end too its just to maintain data consistency state in table if developer commit some mistak...Btw Thanks for answering my post, Vote-up for your attention and concern!