# how to use variable as a column name in trigger

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers

i try to create some trigger for my web database but there is not working code for my trigger here the problem

```
BEGIN
DECLARE t INT;
DECLARE b INT;
DECLARE ir INT;
DECLARE tgl INT;
DECLARE kol VARCHAR(3);



SET tgl = "(SELECT RIGHT(booking_checkin, 2) FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = NEW.booking.id)";

SET ir = "(SELECT booked_room_id FROM pt_booked_rooms WHERE booking_id = NEW.booking.id)";

SET b = "(SELECT MID(booking_checkin , 6,2) FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = NEW.booking_id)";

SET t = "SELECT IF((SELECT LEFT(booking_checkin, 4) FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = NEW.booking_id) = 2019 ,'0','1')";

SET kol = "d" + tgl;

UPDATE pt_rooms_availabilities
set kol = kol + (SELECT `booking_nights` FROM `pt_bookings` WHERE booking_id = NEW.booking_id)
WHERE room_id = ir AND y = t AND m= b; 
END
```

the problem is var kol do not read as a column name 
maybe anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in a trigger. In general, you could use [dynamic sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to use variable column names, see e.g. [Dynamic conversion of string into column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13282718). This is however [not allowed in stored functions or triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12568577).

You could use [`if then else`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) to have a different `insert` statement for each situation, something like `if tgl = 7 then update ... set d7 = d7 + ... elseif tgl = 122 then update ... set d122 = d122 + ...`.

In most situations though, you can and should avoid this by table design.

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but you could just add a column `tglcode` to your table, store that value there and then add `where tglcode = tgl` to your `update` statement. It looks as if you (or your predecessor) did that or something similar with the variables `b` and `t` stored in columns `m` and `t`.

If that is a viable solution (or a proper table design) for your problem is hard to say though without more information. But you definitely cannot use the variable `kol` the way you did in a trigger.

Comment: oh i see the problem i think i should trying to use dynamic sql thanks for your answer

Comment: Not sure if you saw it (or if I misunderstood your comment), but unfortunately you cannot use dynamic sql in a trigger (just in stored procedures). (You may be able to redesign you app in a way that you insert/update into that table via a stored procedure so you do not need a trigger to do the afterwork).

Comment: my problem is solved i use the stored procedure to update my table,  i think the trigger is the only way , but now i find 2 way to this case  1- with stored procedure 2 -  just trick your php code and it works  ;)